# ExactTarget: Synchronizing ExactTarget and Salesforce Contacts - Best practice?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, etl, sync

Hello ExactTarget and Salesforce experts,

This time, I need a little help in understanding how ExactTarget and Salesforce work together...

In this question I will be referring to a previous question, so for starters, here's the link:

[ExactTarget: Common data loading strategies?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50580/exacttarget-common-data-loading-strategies)

I would like to take another step back and look at how ExactTarget and Salesforce are integrated into eachother. I had this naive notion that customers/contacts are automatically synchronized to and from ExactTarget from and to Salesforce. After researching a little and finding various Apps on AppExchange which do more or less that, I am not that sure that this works out of the box anymore.

So, my questions are the following:

- There does not seem to be an "out-of-the-box-automatic-no-worries" synchronization mechanism in place for getting data between Salesforce and ExactTarget; is that correct?

For propagating customer data changes, our company would have two possibilities:

- Leveraging a third party app for the ET-SF synchronization (like, Cazoomi; other suggestions?)
- Implementing a custom integration (based on e.g. IBM Cast Iron) just as the one we will have between our SAP system and Salesforce, effectively treating ET as a totally independent data source and sink.

Is there anybody here who has experience with such Enterprise scenarios?

In referral to my previous question: The decision on how to synchronize between SF and ET will have an impact on which data has to be loaded into ET and by which means. If there exists a sync between ET and SF as an App, only data not available inside Salesforce would need to be loaded into ET using a generic ETL tool.

Any input is appreciated.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer is now rather deprecated. The v5 Connector has now been renamed to [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/). This still enables you to create Import activities like the previous connector, however you can now use the Data Stream feature in Contact Builder to [synchronize fields](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/interact_with_synchronized_data_sources/) between a Salesforce Object and a Data Extension. Note that this feature does not synchronize the records (as they are effectively importing to a Data Extension), but you can update which fields are synchronized.

To update data from a Marketing Cloud Data Extension to Sales Cloud, you can either use a Script Activity in an Automation, which requires using SSJS with the Sales Cloud REST API, or alternatively use the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/salesforce/UpdateSingleSalesforceObject.html) AMPscript function to update a record — for example, in an email at send time, or when a form is submitted on a CloudPage.

Comment: does this connector support realtime or near realtime data sync to SFDC? Or it is just periodic sync?

Comment: It’s a scheduled upsert every 15 minutes (or a longer interval).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at using the [Salesforce v5 Integration](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/) and using [Salesforce Data Extensions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_data_extensions/). With this integration, you can send to Accounts, Contacts, Leads, Campaigns and Person Account objects within Salesforce.